# Call functions within event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have written two functions in JavaScript code as follows

```
Manager = FormManager.extend({
    First: function () {
     var response = this.Second("Feature"); //I'm able to get the alert
     
     //I have added a click event handler
     $('#element').on('click', function(){
       var newResponse = this.Second("Bug"); //The alert is not poping
     });

    }

    Second: function (type) {
     alert(type);
     //Performs certain operation
    }
});
```

> **Error:** Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'Second'

I also tried without using **`this`** keyword like:

```
Second("Bug") // Error: There is no method
```

Whereas this a simplified format (in-order to show a simple example) on my program that I'm playing with.  I'm struggling to find out the reason.

Can someone direct me to the right path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using incorrect `this`. try this way. `this` inside the handler represents `#element` not the context of the function itself.

```
 var self = this; //cache the context here
 $('#element').on('click', function(){
   var newResponse = self.Second("Bug"); //Access it with self
 });
```

Also i think you are missing a comma after `First` function definision and before `Second` function.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9HTx/)**

The reason being the callback you give gets invoked from within the context of the element so your `this` context changes. `this` context refers to the context from where the callback was invoked. But there are other ways to get around this like using [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) while binding your callback with jquery, using EcmaScript5 [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) etc. But ideally you don't want to do that because most of the cases you would need the context of the element there inside the handler.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for a awesome explanation.  I got your point, for me this is something new I playing with this type of function declaration.  Is there anything special about this kind of method declaration?

Comment: @user1671639 Nothing bad about this. But if you are looking at having more of an object model type declaration you can take a look at EcmaScript5 `Object.create` pattern. But again that helps when you are running on tenants like Node.js, but only newer browsers support this. Other wise these are more of a statix method bindings as you don't need an instance on them.

Comment: Once again Thank you.  I got it,  since we're using backbonejs and that the reason they followed this approach.  Sorry for asking this, Is there any quick links that you could refer me regarding different function declaration in JS/ jQuery(if any).

Comment: There are many patterns tha each framworks use. You can look up javascript patterns or the newer [ecma5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) , here is [jquery plugin authoring pattern](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

Answer (score 2):

Every time you use the `this` context variable in a function you have to consider what its value is.

Specifically that value will be whatever value the *caller* specified, whether by using `myObj.mymethod(...)`, or `mymethod.call(myObj, ...)`, or `mymethod.apply(myObj, [ ... ])`.

When your anonymous function `$('#element').on('click', ...)` is invoked jQuery will set the context to the HTML DOM element - it's no longer referring to your object.

The simplest work around is to obtain a copy of `this` outside of the callback, and then refer to that copy inside the closure, i.e.:

```
var that = this;
$('#element').on('click', function() {
     // use that instead of this, here
     console.log(this);    // #element
     console.log(that);    // your object
});
```

Another method is using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
$('#element').on('click', (function() {
     console.log(this);    // your object
}).bind(this));
```

or with jQuery you can use `$.proxy` for the same effect, since `.bind` is an ES5 function.

I actually prefer the `var that = this` method, since it doesn't break the jQuery convention that `this` refers to the element associated with the event.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your valuable answer,  I usually declare function like `function First() {` or `First = function() {`.  Is there anything special about this kind of method declaration?

Comment: Sorry I have got my answer from @PSL.  Thanks for pointing me `$.proxy`, this was quite new to me